# Is a (Dirac) Particle Where $\vec{p} = (p^1,0,0)$ in an Eigenstate of Helicity?

Tags: momentum, dirac-equation, spinors, helicity

Is a particle where $\vec{p} = (p^1,0,0)$ an eigenstate of the helicity operator?

First, can I determine this without doing the math? Second, I also wanna prove it mathematically but doing the math I could not prove this.

Answer (score 1):

Any plane wave *may* be an eigenstate of helicity; it does not depend on what direction the momentum points.  For the $x$-momentum eigenstate described in the question, the helicity operator is $h=\vec{\sigma}\cdot\hat{p}=\sigma_{x}$.  So if the spin part of the wave function is in an eigenstate of $\sigma_{x}$, then the whole state is an eigenstate of helicity.  However, it is also perfectly possible to have a spin state that is a linear combination of the up and down $x$-spin states; in that case, the state is not an eigenstate of helicity.  If the momentum pointed in another direction, the analysis would be essentially the same, except the spin operator would be a different linear combination of Pauli matrices.